# MATLAB surface plot with boundary line

Tags: matlab

I am running a code, where I plot a 2D function using surf:

```
    surf(X1,Y1,phi1,'EdgeColor','None')
    view(2)
    colorbar
```

Now this produces the result on the picture attached.[image: surface plot]

I would like to draw a hexagonal boundary line around this function. The exact points at which this should lie is contained in a matrix in my script which has ones for all points inside the hexagon, and zeros outside. With this, how can I draw a clear black boundary line on the surface plot?

Comment: details: you can use `pcolor` instead of `surf`+`view(2)`

Comment: For your problem I would use the function `contour`. Use `hold on` to draw a new plot in the same figure.

Comment: please post a [mcve]. Show us those points and more or less what do you want it to look like  Do you want the poitns outside the hexagon not to be ploted? to be ploted in another color?